# How to show that the cumulative hazard function is equal to the formula below?

Tags: survival, hazard, numerical-integration

I need help to show the equation below.

$$H(t)=ln[\frac{mrl(t)}{mrl(0)}]+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{mrl(u)}du$$

where mrl is the mean residual life using

$$h(t)=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}mrl(t)+1}{mrl(t)}$$

Comment: Derivating $H$ yields $h$, where do you encounter a difficulty ?

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent I do know that. I need a step by step proof starting with h(t) not the other way round.

Comment: $h(t)=u'(t)/u(t)+1/u(t)$, treat the two terms

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent Thank you for the suggestion. I have this now $\int_{0}^{t} h(u) du=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\frac{d}{du}mrl(u)}{mrl(u)}du+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{mrl(u)}du$. I tried using integration by parts for the first integral but it got more complicated. My calculus is poor so I am not sure what to next.

Comment: You just have to know that $\ln(f(u))$ is a primitive of $f'(u)/f(u)$.